# Meta Descriptions Blank in Serps

Tags: meta-description

Most of the meta descriptions in my articles are not appearing in SERP. [image]

This has happened over the last 12 hours. Updated Yoast and made some Elementor theme changes the night before. Site was also down. Anyone know what's causing this??